# react-bootstrap doesn't rendering properly

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm rendering a modal component, and I'm getting this back :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljvew.png)

**why's the xClose button looks like this?**

Here's my modal component :

```
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap'

const TodoPopup = (props : {show : boolean, onHide : () => void} ) => {
    return (
        <Modal
      {...props}
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      centered
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
          Modal heading
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
        <p>
          This is a modal example
        </p>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
    );
};

export default TodoPopup;
```

I copied and pasted from documentation here : [react-bootstrap documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/)

[image: generated spans inside close button class]

Comment: You might be missing [CSS](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets)?

Comment: I've added the import, but still same results

Comment: any help please?

Comment: I have just tried using the example with a button to open the modal from the documentation and I can't reproduce the issue. Can you inspect the "X" button on your browser and see if the `.btn-close` class had the [correct CSS properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1PcC.png)?

Comment: I've noticed that inside my .btn-close class it makes 2 span tags child, which I didn't make them. and I'm missing the CSS of the .btn-close class, maybe that's the problematic factor. Adding an image of the 2 generated spans

Comment: That is definetely different from what I have, I got the following for the "X" button: `<button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close"></button>`.
I am using react-bootstrap@2.0.0-rc.1 with bootstrap@5.1.1, which correspond to the documentation page you linked, is it what you are using?

Comment: after changing into your html button tag - it worked. but, why is react rendering my close button like this...?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap version 5.1.3 and react-bootstrap version 1.6.4

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it,
I downgraded my bootstrap version to match it with my react-bootstrap version.

Comment: You should not give an answer to your question with this type of comment please delete it and close your question